# How is it possible that animals that produce venom do not end up being poisoned?

Tags: poison

My question is kind of naïve. Some living organisms are known to be capable of producing highly lethal venom to defend themselves (snakes is probably the first example to come to mind, but it is also true for many kinds of toads, marine organisms, various insects and so on). So, they must store it some where within their bodies. One could expect these substances to gradually diffuse into tissues surrounding the venom reservoir that would result in killing cells, poisoning or necrosis of the tissues. It is not difficult to arrive at a conclusion what would be the final outcome of this process for the whole organism. We know it does not happen. Why? What prevents venom from spreading?

Comment: Have you searched this site? I’m almost sure this question has been asked before. And what research have you done elsewhere?

Comment: the venom injected by a snake will break down in the digestion of the prey,venom is different from poison,venom is injected and poison is eaten.

Comment: If an animal produces a venom, most likely immunity to that venom co-evolved along with it. If it didn't, obviously the species would no longer exist.

Comment: Quite various strategies: Specialized cells, glands and organs, protective molecules (e.g. inhibitors), physical barriers (e.g. tough, fibrous capsules), pH and activation required (change in pH or the presence of a certain enzyme needed for activation), target specificity (receptors' specificity), and most fascinating: autoimmunity.